# Planet of hostile plants with spores, hero rescues injured co-worker

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, plants

Another anthology short story I read in the mid 70s-80s.

This is set on a planet which is covered with large hostile plants.

The air is thick with moulds and spores so humans working there have to wear protective suits with air filters. If, for some reason, their helmet gets broken or suit ripped, spores will immediately get in and consume them.

I think earthmen are on the planet to harvest resources such a plant oils or just to do research. They don't think the plants are sentient but maybe they are.

When working somewhere remote from base one man has to rescue another worker, possibly a woman, after a vehicle crash or breakdown and get them both to base despite hostile plants and duct tape clothing repairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a chance this is "[Parasite Planet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47490)" by Stanley G. Weinbaum.

The molds:

> One breath of unfiltered air anywhere near the warm edge of the twilight zone was quick and very painful death; ...the spores of those fierce Venusian molds, and they'd have sprouted furry and nauseating masses in his nostrils, his mouth, his lungs, and eventually in his ears and eyes.

Harvesting resources:

- The protagonist is collecting "xixtchil pods".

One man has to rescue another worker:

- The protagonist meets a stranded woman and together they survive the many dangers of the planet, including the large hostile plants you mention.

A much more detailed answer can be found here: [Trying to track down a sci-fi story about Venus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124234/trying-to-track-down-a-sci-fi-story-about-venus)

It can be read at the Luminist Archive for Astounding here: https://luminist.org/archives/SF/AST/  February 1935 issue.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I've had a quick scan of the text and it's familiar. Thanks.